# Backbone.js: Best way to clear a all views

Tags: javascript, filter, view, backbone.js

I am using Backbone.js to render a list of items (email recipients) that have different status, eg. confirmed, pending and so on. After the list is rendered there are options for user to filter them so the user can list all recipients, or only confirmed recipients and so on. The items (recipients) are naturally stored in a collection..

My approach is to on a filter event:

1. Clear all item's view's
2. From the app view call a filterOnStatus function in the collection that return all models and adds them to the view.

Step 2 works fine. But what's the best way to clear all items on a collection's view's.

In the Todo example application (http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html) they do something similar. In the app view the following code is used to clear all completed items from the list.

```
clearCompleted: function() {
  _.each(Todos.done(), function(todo){ todo.destroy(); });
  return false;
},
```

The difference here is that they do this by removing the actual model. And that model's view listens for the destroy event which them removes the view.

I want to keep the model.

What's the best way to solve this. Do I in the models need to stored a reference to its views and then iterate over the models and remove the views?

Is there a better approach if I want to filter on attributes in the models?

Answer (score 0):

If your first step is simply clearing **all** items then why don't you add a simple method to your AppView that will do just that, like: `clearList: function() { this.$('.list').html('') }`.

Or even better, you can filter all models and render them to the temporarily element and than replace current list with it. Thus all the filtering will be done in only one DOM call (DOM is slow). Example with jQuery:

```
AppView.filterOnStatus = function() {
    var $fragment = $('<div/>')

    // filter your collection and append rendered views to $fragment

    this.$('.list').html( $fragment.html() )
}
```

Of course there are more complicated ways, but whether you need them depends on what you're trying to achieve. From what I understood this simple approach would be fine enough.

Comment: But with this approach I loose track of my views (every list item is a view). No?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by loosing track? Why would you want to keep it?

Comment: I meant the view object, memory-wise. I'm not calling view.remove(); on it. But your saying that removing the DOM representation from the DOM removes the backbone view automatically?

Comment: Well, I didn't think of it at all. From what I know views' objects are gonna be removed by the garbage collector if there are no references to them and it has nothing to do with DOM at all. You can see that in mentioned todos example `.remove()` simply removes the view representation from DOM. From my 3 years of front-end dev experience I think that you shouldn't think about memory in this case at all. Of course I can be wrong, but it's worth separate investigation I suppose.